# How can I get facing html elements to left-align and right-align, respectively, preferably using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want the "values" to be right-aligned. This is my HTML:

```
<p class="blueBold">Existing Building</p>
<p class="values">19,322 sf</p>
</br>
<p class="blueBold">Acreage</p>
<p class="values">3</p>
```

...and my CSS:

```
.blueBold {
    color: navy;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:'Century Gothic', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
}
.values {
    color: white;
    text-align:right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

What do I need to do to get the values to hug the right edge?

jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/wvuQz/1/

Comment: right edge of the screen (or) right edge of some box?

Comment: This looks like you have tabular data, but the markup is odd. Is there some reason for not using a `table` element? It would be rather simple to right-align the second column.

Comment: This is just simple stuff stuffed into a gomap popup; I thought a table would be overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly. But if you add a `width` then you can have the text right aligned to the box like below:

```
.blueBold {
    color: navy;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:'Century Gothic', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
.values {
    color: white;
    text-align:right;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/wvuQz/3/)

**Note**: This is not for aligning the text to the right edge of the screen. This is for making the text within the `.values` element right align within the box.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `display: inline-block;` which will make the element inline, it is no more a `block level element`, hence there is no space for the text to align to the `left` or to the `right`.

Just wrap the elements inside a `div` and than `float` the element to the `right`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wvuQz/4/)

Also am using

```
.wrap {
   overflow: hidden; /* This will clear floats */
}
```

For a better clearfix, you can also use the below snippet and call the class on parent element.

```
.clear:after {
   clear: both;
   display: table;
   content: "";
}
```

You can also assign `width` to the `.wrap` here, so that elements stay inside boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

A block parent container should have the text align to work. In your case it's the body, itself.. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wvuQz/2/)

```
body {
    background-color: orange;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:)

```
.blueBold {
color: navy;
position:absolute;
font-weight: bold;
font-family:'Century Gothic', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
           }
.values {
color: white;
text-align:right;
      }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wvuQz/5/

Answer (score 1):

The semantic approach:

```
<div>
  <p class="blueBold">Existing Building</p>
  <p class="values pull-right">19,322 sf</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="blueBold">Acreage</p>
  <p class="values pull-right">3</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pull-right {
  float: right;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wvuQz/7/

More Info: 
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/20/semantic-css-with-intelligent-selectors/